# How to find Memory leak in Angular Java script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory

IS there any profile tools to find out exact place where the memory leak is happening ?

Thanks,
Delli/

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/karmadude/a7e1b648682508adb781

Comment: How did this get upvotes if it's asking for a tool recommendation which is considered off-topic for SO?

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a tool or any way to get exact code base/object where I can find out memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience is not possible to show you exactly part of the code which can be added to garbage collection. In general I test a part of my app (a view) make "heap snapshot" and try to eliminate one by one test again and like that find the code with problem.

Also if you use strict mode with a lint, is a good change to don't have problems.

The above point is for JS in general, for Angular in particular, you know have some specific problems, like: watchers, $timeout, $rootScope, etc.

You can check John Papa style guide [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) this will help you to avoid some problems.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a tool or any way to get exact code base/object where I can find out memory leak?